# Vagrant ssh code executing gives an error

Tags: laravel, command, vagrant, homestead

I'm stuck with a silly problem. I'm using **Vagrant** with **Homestead** and **Laravel** for developing. The problem is when I go to a project and try to execute any command it gives me the following error:

[image: Error message]

I have set the `PATH = "usr/local/bin"`. 
I'm stuck with this for 2 days and I don't know what to do so If you had the same problem please share your experience with me.

Comment: Where did you set your path? Are you sure it's exported in your current session? When you type `echo $PATH` what is the output?

Comment: result is /usr/local/bin

Comment: Hmmm...normally the way to add something to the path is to append or prepend to the PATH like so: `PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin`, so I'm wondering if maybe by overwriting the entire PATH you messed something up. Can you try this: `PATH=$(getconf PATH):usr/local/bin`.  This will get your default PATH back and then append usr/local/bin to it.

Comment: PATH=$(getconf PATH):usr/local/bin this code has given "The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
getconf: command not found"

Comment: "PATH=$PATH:usr/local/bin" this one worked for me but after this when I enter artisan it give me the following "-bash: ./artisan: Permission denied"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be sure that your PATH is set correctly: `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`

If you're getting a `permission denied` error try giving yourself execute permission on `artisan` and `laravel` like so:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/laravel`

Comment: I do'nt know what the problem is but it gives "sudo" command not found

Comment: I think your path might be messed up. Try the full path to sudo and see if it's there: `/usr/bin/sudo`.

Comment: okay, then your path is definitely messed up. Try this: PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin then try again and see if you still have problems.

Comment: Cool, would you mind upvoting my answer? I'll include the final solution there. Thanks! Glad to help!